# Swing and events

Tags: java, swing, layout, jbutton, windowbuilder

Well, this is a very newie cuestion. Im stating to write by myself the code of my GUI applications with the help of window builder, i have decided to stop using netbeans couse ive read some peope in here that said that would be good. You may think i havent investigate, but trust me, i did my homework...

I tryed the way oracle says:

1. Declare an event handler class and specify that the class either implements an ActionListener interface or extends a class that implements an ActionListener interface. For example:

> public class MyClass implements ActionListener {
>
> Register an instance of the event handler class as a listener on one or more components. For example:
>
> > someComponent.addActionListener(instanceOfMyClass);
> >
> > Include code that implements the methods in listener interface. For example:
> >
> > > public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
> > >       ...//code that reacts to the action... 
> > >       }
> > >       
> > >       and my own way (wrong, off course, but i dont know whats wrong)

```
package Todos;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Main extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
protected JButton btnNewButton;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Main frame = new Main();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });


}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Main() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    //setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(false);
    //setIconImage(Image imagen);
    setTitle("");
    setSize(java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
    setPreferredSize(java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    this.btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
    this.btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            asd(arg0);
        }
    });
    this.getContentPane().add(this.btnNewButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);
}

public void asd(ActionEvent arg0) {
    this.getContentPane().add(new JButton("asd"));
}
}
```

The cuestion is, why this code doesnt work, the JButton im trying to add to the JFrame with the ActionPerformed event is not visible after i click.

This is an example code, may look silly, but i think it simplifies the cuestion, since my problem is in a few lines of code its not neccesary to show you the hole proyect.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: What is the problem? You didn't create or implement action listener as you described but use inner class instead.

Comment: Sorry, edited with my question...
@nikpon, ive used an inner class to access the JFrame content like NetBeans does. Thats why i said "my own way"(even so i did it the way oracle says, didnt work for me either)

Comment: The component (button) isn't visible because container (JFrame) didn't know how to make it appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
public void asd(ActionEvent arg0) {
    this.getContentPane().add(new JButton("asd"));
}
```

Form [Container.add()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component%29) javadoc:

> This method changes layout-related information, and therefore,
>   invalidates the component hierarchy. ***If the container has already been
>   displayed, the hierarchy must be validated thereafter in order to
>   display the added component.***

You need to call `validate()` method to make added button visible:

```
public void asd(ActionEvent arg0) {
    this.getContentPane().add(new JButton("asd"));
    this.getContentPane().validate();
}
```